# Good book/online tutorials for setting up domains and email accounts on Windows Server 2008

Tags: email, windows-server-2008, active-directory, iis-7

I'm looking for recommendations on how to correctly setup multiple domain names and email addresses on Windows Server 2008.

As it's such a broad subject I thought a book would be better than asking individual questions here.

The way i'd setup a domain usually (on a Windows VPS Server, with them all being hosted from a single IP is:)

- Go into IIS7 and add a new site
- Enter the website name, set IP address and put the **host header** to www.mysite.com

I normally in the past have left the App Pool as DefaultAppPool - I'm not sure if I should be creating a new app pool for each site or not....

Also I don't know when I should be adding a "Website" or "Web Application" when adding a new site. So I think I need a full book on the subject.

If anybody can recommend some reading material that would be great.

I've used Active Directory in the past at work for setting up user accounts for access to our systems such as WSS sites etc, but don't know how to configure email accounts, or the correct way to setup AD to run seperate accounts for different sites/applications.

These aren't really additional questions above, so please don't close for being off topic. It's more to give you an idea of what i'm looking for from a book.

The book can be as techinical as needs to be. I'm a C# .NET developer, but by no means a professional admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At school we use windows server 2008 in 24 hours by Joe Habraken its from the teach yourself line. 
It is described with screenshots what you have to do and you get some detailed background information.